# Add storybook to a vue.js webpack project parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0) <template>

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack, storybook

I have a problem when starting storybook after adding it to a new vuejs project.

Apparently when including a .vue file it is not interpreted correctly ...

Here are all the steps I performed to setup the vue.js project and adding the storybook (I'm on Windows 10):

1) Command line: `vue init webpack app-test`

```
? Project name app-test
? Project description A Vue.js project
? Author email@email.email
? Standalone build view
? Install vue-router? Yes
? Use ESLint to lint your code? Yes
? Pick an ESLint preset Standard
? Set up unit tests Yes
? Pick a test runner jest
? Setup e2e tests with Nightwatch? No.
? Should we run `npm install` for you after the project has been created? (recommended) npm

   view-cli · Generated "app-test".

Installing project dependencies ...

[...]
```

2) Then I followed this tutorial to add storybook to my project (Manual setup): https://storybook.js.org/docs/guides/guide-vue/

But when I try to start storybook I get several errors:

```
> start-storybook

info @storybook/vue v5.2.8
info
info => Loading presets
WARN   Failed to load preset: "C:\\Users\\Firstname Lastname\\Desktop\\workspace\\website\\components\\front-end\\app\\node_modules\\@storybook\\vue\\dist\\server\\framework-preset-vue.js"
ERR! Error: Cannot find module 'vue-loader/lib/plugin'
ERR!     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:655:15)
ERR!     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:25)
ERR!     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:19)
ERR!     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
ERR!     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Firstname Lastname\Desktop\workspace\website\components\front-end\app\node_modules\@storybook\vue\dist\server\framework-preset-vue.js:11:38)
ERR!     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:805:30)
ERR!     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:10)
ERR!     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:672:32)
ERR!     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:12)
ERR!     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:604:3)
ERR!     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:19)
ERR!     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
ERR!     at interopRequireDefault (C:\Users\Firstname Lastname\Desktop\workspace\website\components\front-end\app\node_modules\@storybook\core\dist\server\presets.js:20:18)
ERR!     at loadPreset (C:\Users\Firstname Lastname\Desktop\workspace\website\components\front-end\app\node_modules\@storybook\core\dist\server\presets.js:30:17)
ERR!     at Array.map (<anonymous>)
ERR!     at loadPresets (C:\Users\Firstname Lastname\Desktop\workspace\website\components\front-end\app\node_modules\@storybook\core\dist\server\presets.js:59:26)
ERR!  { Error: Cannot find module 'vue-loader/lib/plugin'
ERR!     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:655:15)
ERR!     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:25)
ERR!     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:19)
ERR!     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
ERR!     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Firstname Lastname\Desktop\workspace\website\components\front-end\app\node_modules\@storybook\vue\dist\server\framework-preset-vue.js:11:38)
ERR!     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:805:30)
ERR!     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:10)
ERR!     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:672:32)
ERR!     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:12)
ERR!     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:604:3)
ERR!     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:19)
ERR!     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
ERR!     at interopRequireDefault (C:\Users\Firstname Lastname\Desktop\workspace\website\components\front-end\app\node_modules\@storybook\core\dist\server\presets.js:20:18)
ERR!     at loadPreset (C:\Users\Firstname Lastname\Desktop\workspace\website\components\front-end\app\node_modules\@storybook\core\dist\server\presets.js:30:17)
ERR!     at Array.map (<anonymous>)
ERR!     at loadPresets (C:\Users\Firstname Lastname\Desktop\workspace\website\components\front-end\app\node_modules\@storybook\core\dist\server\presets.js:59:26)
ERR!   stack:
ERR!    "Error: Cannot find module 'vue-loader/lib/plugin'\n    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:655:15)\n    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:25)\n    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:19)\n    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)\n    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\\Users\\Firstname Lastname\\Desktop\\workspace\\website\\components\\front-end\\app\\node_modules\\@storybook\\vue\\dist\\server\\framework-preset-vue.js:11:38)\n    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:805:30)\n    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:10)\n    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:672:32)\n    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:12)\n    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:604:3)\n    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:19)\n    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)\n    at interopRequireDefault (C:\\Users\\Firstname Lastname\\Desktop\\workspace\\website\\components\\front-end\\app\\node_modules\\@storybook\\core\\dist\\server\\presets.js:20:18)\n    at loadPreset (C:\\Users\\Firstname Lastname\\Desktop\\workspace\\website\\components\\front-end\\app\\node_modules\\@storybook\\core\\dist\\server\\presets.js:30:17)\n    at Array.map (<anonymous>)\n    at loadPresets (C:\\Users\\Firstname Lastname\\Desktop\\workspace\\website\\components\\front-end\\app\\node_modules\\@storybook\\core\\dist\\server\\presets.js:59:26)",
ERR!   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
info => Loading presets
WARN   Failed to load preset: "C:\\Users\\Firstname Lastname\\Desktop\\workspace\\website\\components\\front-end\\app\\node_modules\\@storybook\\vue\\dist\\server\\framework-preset-vue.js"
ERR! Error: Cannot find module 'vue-loader/lib/plugin'
ERR!     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:655:15)
ERR!     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:25)
ERR!     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:19)
ERR!     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
ERR!     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Firstname Lastname\Desktop\workspace\website\components\front-end\app\node_modules\@storybook\vue\dist\server\framework-preset-vue.js:11:38)
ERR!     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:805:30)
ERR!     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:10)
ERR!     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:672:32)
ERR!     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:12)
ERR!     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:604:3)
ERR!     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:19)
ERR!     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
ERR!     at interopRequireDefault (C:\Users\Firstname Lastname\Desktop\workspace\website\components\front-end\app\node_modules\@storybook\core\dist\server\presets.js:20:18)
ERR!     at loadPreset (C:\Users\Firstname Lastname\Desktop\workspace\website\components\front-end\app\node_modules\@storybook\core\dist\server\presets.js:30:17)
ERR!     at Array.map (<anonymous>)
ERR!     at loadPresets (C:\Users\Firstname Lastname\Desktop\workspace\website\components\front-end\app\node_modules\@storybook\core\dist\server\presets.js:59:26)
ERR!  { Error: Cannot find module 'vue-loader/lib/plugin'
ERR!     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:655:15)
ERR!     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:25)
ERR!     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:19)
ERR!     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
ERR!     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Firstname Lastname\Desktop\workspace\website\components\front-end\app\node_modules\@storybook\vue\dist\server\framework-preset-vue.js:11:38)
ERR!     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:805:30)
ERR!     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:10)
ERR!     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:672:32)
ERR!     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:12)
ERR!     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:604:3)
ERR!     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:19)
ERR!     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
ERR!     at interopRequireDefault (C:\Users\Firstname Lastname\Desktop\workspace\website\components\front-end\app\node_modules\@storybook\core\dist\server\presets.js:20:18)
ERR!     at loadPreset (C:\Users\Firstname Lastname\Desktop\workspace\website\components\front-end\app\node_modules\@storybook\core\dist\server\presets.js:30:17)
ERR!     at Array.map (<anonymous>)
ERR!     at loadPresets (C:\Users\Firstname Lastname\Desktop\workspace\website\components\front-end\app\node_modules\@storybook\core\dist\server\presets.js:59:26)
ERR!   stack:
ERR!    "Error: Cannot find module 'vue-loader/lib/plugin'\n    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:655:15)\n    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:25)\n    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:19)\n    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)\n    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\\Users\\Firstname Lastname\\Desktop\\workspace\\website\\components\\front-end\\app\\node_modules\\@storybook\\vue\\dist\\server\\framework-preset-vue.js:11:38)\n    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:805:30)\n    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:10)\n    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:672:32)\n    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:12)\n    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:604:3)\n    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:19)\n    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)\n    at interopRequireDefault (C:\\Users\\Firstname Lastname\\Desktop\\workspace\\website\\components\\front-end\\app\\node_modules\\@storybook\\core\\dist\\server\\presets.js:20:18)\n    at loadPreset (C:\\Users\\Firstname Lastname\\Desktop\\workspace\\website\\components\\front-end\\app\\node_modules\\@storybook\\core\\dist\\server\\presets.js:30:17)\n    at Array.map (<anonymous>)\n    at loadPresets (C:\\Users\\Firstname Lastname\\Desktop\\workspace\\website\\components\\front-end\\app\\node_modules\\@storybook\\core\\dist\\server\\presets.js:59:26)",
ERR!   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
info => Using default Webpack setup.
10% building 1/1 modules 0 active(node:20820) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on `.hooks` instead
webpack built 67e016cd23aad0230032 in 12596ms
× ｢wdm｣: Hash: 67e016cd23aad0230032
Version: webpack 4.41.4
Time: 12596ms
Built at: 2019-12-25 22:39:17
                                          Asset      Size        Chunks
  Chunk Names
                                    iframe.html  3.05 KiB                [emitted]

            main.67e016cd23aad0230032.bundle.js  6.15 KiB          main  [emitted] [immutable]
  main
        main.67e016cd23aad0230032.bundle.js.map  1.84 KiB          main  [emitted] [dev]
  main
    runtime~main.67e016cd23aad0230032.bundle.js  31.2 KiB  runtime~main  [emitted] [immutable]
  runtime~main
runtime~main.67e016cd23aad0230032.bundle.js.map  32.3 KiB  runtime~main  [emitted] [dev]
  runtime~main
    vendors~main.67e016cd23aad0230032.bundle.js  2.91 MiB  vendors~main  [emitted] [immutable]  [big]  vendors~main
vendors~main.67e016cd23aad0230032.bundle.js.map   2.9 MiB  vendors~main  [emitted] [dev]
  vendors~main
Entrypoint main [big] = runtime~main.67e016cd23aad0230032.bundle.js runtime~main.67e016cd23aad0230032.bundle.js.map vendors~main.67e016cd23aad0230032.bundle.js vendors~main.67e016cd23aad0230032.bundle.js.map main.67e016cd23aad0230032.bundle.js main.67e016cd23aad0230032.bundle.js.map
[0] multi ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/common/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/preview/globals.js ./.storybook/config.js ./node_modules/webpack-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&quiet=true 64 bytes {main} [built]
[./.storybook/config.js] 118 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/common/polyfills.js] 120 bytes {vendors~main} [built]
[./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/preview/globals.js] 93 bytes {vendors~main} [built]
[./node_modules/@storybook/core/node_modules/core-js/features/symbol/index.js] 359 bytes {vendors~main} [built]
[./node_modules/@storybook/core/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js] 23 KiB {vendors~main} [built]
[./node_modules/@storybook/core/node_modules/webpack/buildin/harmony-module.js] (webpack)/buildin/harmony-module.js 573 bytes {vendors~main} [built]
[./node_modules/@storybook/core/node_modules/webpack/buildin/module.js] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 497 bytes {vendors~main} [built]
[./node_modules/@storybook/vue/dist/client/index.js] 1.21 KiB {vendors~main} [built]
[./node_modules/airbnb-js-shims/index.js] 40 bytes {vendors~main} [built]
[./node_modules/global/window.js] 232 bytes {vendors~main} [built]
[./node_modules/querystring-es3/index.js] 127 bytes {vendors~main} [built]
[./node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js] 161 bytes {vendors~main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-hot-middleware/client-overlay.js] 2.17 KiB {vendors~main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&quiet=true] 7.68 KiB {vendors~main} [built]
    + 758 hidden modules

ERROR in ./src/components/atoms/Button.vue 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <template>
|   <div>{{ label }}</div>
| </template>
 @ ./stories/mybutton/index.stories.js 2:0-61 16:28-36
 @ ./stories sync \.stories\.js$
 @ ./.storybook/config.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/common/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/preview/globals.js ./.storybook/config.js ./node_modules/webpack-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&quiet=true
Child HtmlWebpackCompiler:
                          Asset      Size               Chunks  Chunk Names
    __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_0  6.53 KiB  HtmlWebpackPlugin_0  HtmlWebpackPlugin_0
    Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_0 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_0
    [./node_modules/@storybook/core/node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/templates/index.ejs] 2.18 KiB {HtmlWebpackPlugin_0} [built]

WARN Broken build, fix the error above.
WARN You may need to refresh the browser.
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "modules": false,
      "targets": {
        "browsers": ["> 1%", "last 2 versions", "not ie <= 8"]
      }
    }],
    "stage-2"
  ],
  "plugins": ["transform-vue-jsx", "transform-runtime"],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": ["env", "stage-2"],
      "plugins": ["transform-vue-jsx", "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs", "dynamic-import-node"]
    }
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "app-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Description",
  "author": "Email <email@email.email>",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "unit": "jest --config test/unit/jest.conf.js --coverage",
    "test": "npm run unit",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src test/unit",
    "build": "node build/build.js",
    "storybook": "start-storybook"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.7",
    "@storybook/vue": "^5.2.8",
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.1",
    "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "^21.0.2",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "^1.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.5.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-vue": "^2.0.2",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "eslint": "^4.15.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^10.2.1",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "jest": "^22.0.4",
    "jest-serializer-vue": "^0.3.0",
    "node-notifier": "^5.1.2",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "ora": "^1.2.0",
    "portfinder": "^1.0.13",
    "postcss-import": "^11.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.8",
    "postcss-url": "^7.2.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
    "storybook": "^5.1.11",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "vue-jest": "^1.0.2",
    "vue-loader": "^13.7.3",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "webpack": "^3.12.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 6.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

**index.stories.js**

```
import MyButton from '../../src/components/atoms/Button.vue'

export default { title: 'Button' }

export const withText = () => '<my-button>with text</my-button>'

export const withEmoji = () => '<my-button>   </my-button>'

export const asAComponent = () => ({
  components: { MyButton },
  template: '<my-button :rounded="true">rounded</my-button>'
})
```

**Button.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>{{ label }}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'my-button',
  data () {
    return {
      label: 'Mon bouton'
    }
  }
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
div {
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
}
</style>
```

Adam.